# Adding a tool to an already created chefbook/box

Tags: test-kitchen

I am trying to learn kitchen/chef and I am following the tutorial provided here

http://kitchen.ci/docs/getting-started/installing

Right now I am stuck at question rather than a problem. The given tutorial creates a git-cookbook. Now what i want to know that we are we telling the kitchen to create a box with "git" installed ?

I re-did the whole tutorial without an empty `metadata.rb` instead of providing anything in it (as per tutorial), i left it empty and ran `kitchen init --driver=kitchen-vagrant`. As expected, it created the cookbook/box without git installed on it.

I then added following line in `metadata.rb`

```
name "git"
version "0.1.0"
```

And then ran `kitchen converge default-ubuntu-1204`. What i was expecting that it will update my cookbook/box with git installed on it but it didn't.

Do i have to do `kitchen init` again ? wouldn't it overwrite my existing .kitchen.yml file and all the changes i have done in it ? What is best way to install a tool in an already created cookbook/box ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to actually use the git recipe somewhere to get the changes you're looking for. Either with an

```
include_recipe 'cookbookname::recipename'
```

EDIT: The include_recipe resource goes in a recipe you're using in your runlist. Think of it as copy/pasting the entire recipe you're including into the file you include it in.

or by adding it to the runlist of the suite in your .kitchen.yml

```
suites:
- name: <suite name>
  run_list:
  - recipe[<cookbookname::recipename>]
  - recipe[<cookbookname::recipename>]...
```

When you converge kitchen will pick up the difference in your configuration and add new things in if you told it to but it wont remove items without explicit instruction.